# How to Set Date to JdateChooser in java?

Tags: java

[image: JCalendar]

I used jcalendar_1.4.jar and I have a date declared like this

```
String date = "13 Oct 2016";
```

I would like to set this date into JDateChooser text box by using method JDateChooser.setDate

How can I convert my string into date format?

Comment: You can use Date.parse method to convert string to date object. SimpleDateFormat can be used to format as well.

Comment: (A) You should link to a site for whatever library you are mentioning such as this `Jcalendar`. (B) Parsing date strings has been handled on Stack Overflow [over two thousand times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+date+parse) already. Please explain how none of those address your question.

Comment: Unfortunately `JDateChooser.setDate()` requires an old-fashoined `Date` object, while we’d have preferred to avoid that outdated class. I suggest you use a `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing your string into a `LocalDate` and convert it to `Date`. Use your search engine to find the details.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using this easily by SimpleDateFormat command

```
   String date = "13 Oct 2016";
   java.util.Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);
   JdateChooser.setDate(date2);
```

and also you can use any date format.

Comment: I got `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "13 Oct 2016"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar ca = new GregorianCalendar();
String day = ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "";
String month = ca.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + "";
String year = ca.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "";

if (day.length() == 1) {
    day = "0" + day;
}
if (month.length() == 1) {
    month = "0" + month;
}

String dd = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dd);
jDateChooser1.setDate(date);
```

try this set date form computer date

Comment: That looks unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Also it’s not clear how the asker should fit the string of `13 Oct 2016` into it?

Answer (score 0):

The following was first written as an answer to [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332552/how-to-get-a-date-from-jtable-and-insert-it-into-jdatechooser-field). I thought it would be better to have it here so we have all the answers in one place.

The following should work overall, only the details depend on the format of the dates in the `JTable` (from the other question). I have assumed that from the `JTable` you get a string like `03/07/2018` (I am told that this format would be commonplace in Portugal). In this case the following formatter will be fine for parsing it. If the string is in a different format, the formatter will have to be different too.

```
        DateTimeFormatter dtfFormatador = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("pt-PT"));

        LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(getData, dtfFormatador);
        Instant instante = data.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        Date dateAntiquado = Date.from(instante);
        jdcSeletorDeDatas.setDate(dateAntiquado);
```

Unfortunately `JDateChooser.setDate()` requires an old-fashoined `Date` object, while we’d have preferred to avoid that outdated class. I am using a `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing the string from the `JTable` into a `LocalDate` and converting it to `Date`. `LocalDate` is the class from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, that we should use for a date without time of day.

**Edit:** harsha, your string was

```
    String date = "13 Oct 2016";
```

To parse a string in this format, use the following formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter= DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Otherwise use the code above, where `jdcSeletorDeDatas` is the `JDateChooser`.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
try {
    String date = "13 Oct 2016";
    Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse(date);
    jDateChooser2.setDate(date2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

- Right Click on JDateChooser
- Go to Properties
- Change dateFormatString as "dd MMM yyyy"

Answer (score -1):

Try to cast the value to the `Date` type. This Worked for me:

```
int SelectRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
jDateChooser1.setDate((Date) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(SelectRow, 2));
```